# Dimension of a subspace and its basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space and let $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ be a fixed vector in $V$. Prove that the collection of elements $A=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ of $V$ with $a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n=0$ is a subspace of $V$. Determine the dimension of the subspace and find its basis.

I've solved the part related to proving that $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is a subspace of $V$.

$A$ is a subspace of $V$ then we can write $\dim(A)\le\dim(V)$

The dimension of $A$ is also equal to the cardinality of its basis.

But i have no clue what to do from here.

If anyone would point me in the right direction or give me a hint, I would be grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

$$(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)=(0,0,\cdots,0)$$

then $\forall v \in V$, the condition holds and hence the dimension of the subspace is $n$ and you can just choose the standard basis.

If $$(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n) \ne (0,0,\cdots,0)$$, then $\exists a_i\ne 0$.

Therefore you can write

$$x_i=-\frac{a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots+a_{i-1}x_{i-1}+a_{i+1}x_{i+1}+\cdots+a_nx_n}{a_i}$$

Therefore for all $v$ in the subspace, we have

$$v=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{i-1},-\frac{a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots+a_{i-1}x_{i-1}+a_{i+1}x_{i+1}+\cdots+a_nx_n}{a_i},x_{i+1},\cdots,x_n)$$
$$=\sum_{j\ne i}x_jv_j$$
where
$$v_j=(0,0,\cdots,1,\cdots,0,-\frac{a_j}{a_i},0,\cdots,0)$$

It is obvious that the $v_j$'s are linearly independent, and the number is $n-1$.

So the dimension of the subspace is $n-1$, and the $v_j$'s is a possible basis set.

Answer (score 1):

Your space seems to be $V=\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the linear map
$$
T\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}
\qquad
T(x_1,\dots,x_n)=a_1x_1+\dots+a_nx_n
$$
Then, by definition, $A=\ker T$.

If $(a_1,\dots,a_n)=(0,\dots,0)$, then $T$ is the zero map and its kernel is $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Otherwise, $T$ is surjective and you can apply the rank-nullity theorem

> $\dim A=n-1$

Comment: It's not necessarily $\mathbb{R}^n$. It could be a generic $n$-dimensional real vector space with some choice of basis.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 No. What can change is the base field. In a generic vector space, the element $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: $(a_1, ..., a_n)$ would denote $\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} a_k e_k$ where $E = \{e_1, \cdots e_n\}$ is a basis for $V$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Sorry, no. That would be wrong: there's no mention at all of a basis of $V$.

Comment: Could you explain why that's wrong then....

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to have given the vector space a name, so I'm going to call it $\ker a$.

Now either $a=0$, in which case everything is in $\ker a$, so we can take the usual basis to be a basis for $\ker a$, or $a$ has some nonzero coordinate, which I will assume is $a_n$.

Then consider the vectors $f_i = (0,\ldots,0,a_n,0,\ldots,0,-a_i)$, where $a_n$ is in the $i$th coordinate. By construction $f_i\cdot a = a_na_i - a_i a_n =0$, so $f_i\in \ker a$, and because $f_i$ is the only vector with a nonzero $i$th coordinate, all of the $f_i$ are linearly independent.  However the dimension of $\ker a$ is $n-1$, since the rank of $a$ as a linear map from $V$ to $k$ where $k$ is our base field is 1, so the nullity of $a$, which is the $\dim \ker a$ must be $n-1$ by rank-nullity. Thus our $n-1$ linearly independent vectors must in fact be a basis. Hence the $f_i$ give a basis for $\ker a$.

Answer (score 0):

The dimension is given by the **number of free variables**.

Let's suppose $\vec a\neq \vec 0$, in this case you only have **one constrain**:

$$a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n=0$$

thus the dimension is $n-1$.

To find a basis you can set:

$x_1=a_2$ and $x_2=-a_1$ and $x_i=0$ $i=3,n$

and so on, in this way you can construct a set of $n-1$ linearly indipendent vectors which satisfy the constrain, that is a basis.

As **an example** you may consider a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by: $$ax+by+cz=0$$

Comment: I can find a case where the dimension is not $n$. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg there is some mistake in my answer?

Comment: Yes. See the other two answers.

Comment: @JohnHughes Ok it's because I've not considered the case $a_i=0$

Comment: Well...the case where $a_i = 0$ for *all* $i$, yes.